# nosetests -v sklearn Failure

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to get my keras and tensorflow-gpu code to work on my new windows 10 64-bit PC with a GPU. I have followed instructions at [Advanced Scikit Installation Intructions](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html) but when I try to test Scikit-learn with nosetest, it fails with the following error:

Please help me fix this issue.

---

```
D:\>nosetests -v sklearn
Failure: TypeError (unorderable types: str() < int()) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: TypeError (unorderable types: str() < int())
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ranaalisaeed\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\nose\failure.py", line 39, in runTest
    raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "c:\users\ranaalisaeed\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\nose\loader.py", line 407, in loadTestsFromName
    module = resolve_name(addr.module)
  File "c:\users\ranaalisaeed\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\nose\util.py", line 312, in resolve_name
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "c:\users\ranaalisaeed\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "c:\users\ranaalisaeed\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "c:\users\ranaalisaeed\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "c:\users\ranaalisaeed\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "c:\users\ranaalisaeed\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 406, in <module>
    if np_version < (1, 12, 0):
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

---

```
D:\>python -c "import nose; nose.main()" -v sklearn
Failure: TypeError (unorderable types: str() < int()) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: TypeError (unorderable types: str() < int())
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ranaalisaeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nose\failure.py", line 39, in runTest
    raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "C:\Users\ranaalisaeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nose\loader.py", line 407, in loadTestsFromName
    module = resolve_name(addr.module)
  File "C:\Users\ranaalisaeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nose\util.py", line 312, in resolve_name
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "C:\Users\ranaalisaeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\ranaalisaeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\ranaalisaeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "C:\Users\ranaalisaeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\ranaalisaeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 406, in <module>
    if np_version < (1, 12, 0):
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

My environment is as follows:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
cycler==0.10.0
h5py==2.7.0rc3
Keras==2.0.0
matplotlib==2.0.0
nose==1.3.7
numpy==1.12.1rc1+mkl
olefile==0.44
opencv-python==3.2.0
packaging==16.8
pandas==0.19.2
Pillow==4.0.0
protobuf==3.2.0
psutil==5.2.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
PyPrind==2.10.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2016.10
PyYAML==3.12
scikit-learn==0.18.1
scipy==0.19.0
six==1.10.0
sklearn==0.0
sklearn-contrib-lightning==0.4.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.0.1
```

Comment: Why do you need to follow the advanced installation instructions for scikit-learn? On windows just use conda to install it then install tensorflow-gpu with pip (see http://www.heatonresearch.com/2017/01/01/tensorflow-windows-gpu.html )

Comment: Thank you for your response rth, I wanted to use native environment, for some reason I am not confortable with using virtual environments. I believe anacona a virtual environment as well as a package manager, is there any obvious benefit for using virtual environment over native pip? Sorry but I am new in this field.

Comment: No anaconda is just scientific python distribution, you can use it directly to install packages without virtual environments if you don't want to. It also work well in combination for pip. For installing scientific python packages on windows I would strongly advise it. Some packages that are installed with pip are already have already good prebuilt binaries for windows (e.g. numpy, scipy, scikit-learn) for others you you don't want to compile them on windows, just use conda...